# webpack imports-loader to window.variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webpack

I'm working on a project with jQuery and Angular. Specifically, it relies on Angular loading with window.jQuery so that jqLite is replaced. Here's the relevant line of the Angular library:

```
jQuery = isUndefined(jqName) ? window.jQuery
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1705

My config for Angular looks like this:

```
loader: "imports-loader?jQuery=jquery,this=>window"
```

However, it seems that `this` is undefined in that particular scope:

```
> console.log(this)
undefined
```

I also tried this, but it raises a parsing error on the `.` in webpack.

```
loader: "imports-loader?window.jQuery=jquery"
```

Comment: Found this (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/542) and using the ProvidePlugin with "window.jQuery": "jquery" works.

Comment: please post it as an answer then, for the benefit of others

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the config I found that ended up working for me:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
]
```

Source: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/542